# Variable does not contain true value. How. Why?

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable when i write its value using `document.write()` i don't get the true value. See this-

```
 <div onclick="a=this;document.write(a)">this is div</div>
```

With this by clicking div i get this`[object HTMLDivElement]`. But this not the true value see how-

```
 <button onclick="[object HTMLDivElement].style.visibility='hidden'">click me</button>
```

when i used this code. I expected that it will hide all div elements. But i didn't got that. Why?

Note:-

i don't want a better way to do this, i want to know the problem in my code.

Comment: Are you just trying to hide that DIV?

Comment: That code is very very wrong.

Comment: i know it is wrong but i am asking what is wrong?

Comment: All of it.  `document.write`, `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing an object to `document.write` will convert the object to a string by calling `.toString()`.

When called on a `<div>` DOM element, `toString()` returns `"[object HTMLDivElement]"`.

This is just a string representation of the object; it is fundamentally impossible to retrieve the original object from that string.

Answer (score 0):

that is because `this` is the `[object HTMLDivElement]` not a boolean value in your first example....

```
<button onclick="this.hidden=true;">click me</button>
```

will work

Comment: i use hidden=true because, frankly, i couldn't care to write the rest out. keep in mind it's just no-specificity mapping to display:none;

Comment: i don't want to hide the button

Answer (score 0):

document.write requires you to send it raw html (a string, basically) but you are mistakenly trying to send it a "div" object instead.

I haven't tested this, but I assume it should work

```
<div onclick="a=this.innerHTML;document.write(a)">this is div</div>
```

or more semantically correctly:

```
<div onclick="a=this;document.write(a.innerHTML)">this is div</div>
```

In other words, get the html source of your "div" object (using its innerHTML property), not the rendered "div" object itself, and send it that.